# Managing 2 npm packages that depend on eachother

Tags: node.js, package, npm

I'm creating a npm package that only contains Sass, a small framework. I only want this package to contain the Sass (and a few grunt plugins) so that someone can install and build it without installing the documentation.

But in the case where someone wants to contribute to the project having only the Sass files isn't all that helpful. They would need the documentation (or an example) to view the changes.

So I would like 2 packages; 1 for the framework and 1 for the documentation.

The documentation package would require the framework, the framework package may or may not require the documentation. (You would never update the framework from documentation, only the documentation, but the framework is needed.)

Documentation required = wanting to contribute to framework

Documentation not required = just wanting to use the framework in a project

Basically, I want to give the person installing the framework the option of getting the docs or not.

Is this possible using `dependencies` vs `devDependencies` vs `peerDependencies`?

Thanks!

Comment: To someone who wants to contribute, wouldn't Github be a better option? They could just clone the repo instead of installing it from npm. You could use npmignore to ignore all the documentation from npm package, which will still remain on Github

Comment: Yep. I had a feeling I was over thinking this. Got so focused on the npm side that I was ignoring Githubs purpose. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From above:
To someone who wants to contribute, wouldn't Github be a better option? They could just clone the repo instead of installing it from npm. You could use npmignore to ignore all the documentation from npm package, which will still remain on Github

Thanks @laggingreflex